# How can I achieve sorting on spring data mongodb on multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I need to sort the data based on the field present in Collection B's Document, by querying on Collection A's document, and A and B can be related by ID.

`Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
List<A> objects = mongoTemplate.find(query, A.class);`

With Pageable object, I can easily achieve sorting and pagination on fields present in Collection A and I want to achieve the same thing for field present in Collection B.

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward, did you run into problems?

Comment: As I am new to monodb, I am struggling to use Aggregation, can u provide me some snippet?

Comment: You'll need a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html?searchProperty=current&query=election#lookup-aggregation) stage to get data from 2 collections, then a [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html#sort-aggregation) stage to order it.  Check out the examples at the bottom of those links.